# Hibernate - Cannot connect to DB

Tags: java, hibernate

I try to use mysql so include mysql.jdbc and these are my hibernate settings.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-configuration>
      <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TekirMobile</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">fenderpass</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
      </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

but when i try to connecto db i get this error:

```
Unable to connect: Cannot establish a connection jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydbname using apache.org.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver(Unable to find a suitable driver)
```

I dont even use derby why i get this error?

Comment: First you need to turn off the firewall then doing other.

Comment: so if i dont turn off firewall, changes are not in effect?

Comment: @user2153566, Please follow this link. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_configuration.htm

Answer (score 0):

You are not specifying the connection driver anywhere. It is telling you it's trying to connect using `apache.org.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver`.

Specify the MySQL driver, in the following way:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
```