# Hibernate - MySQL - Connection to DB

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, connection, driver

I'm trying to connect to a MySQL database using Hibernate 3.6.10 with NetBeans 7.4, but when I try to create a new "Hibernate Mapping Wizard" I reply this error message:

```
Unable to connect: Cannot establish a connection jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydbname using apache.org.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver(Unable to find a suitable driver)
```

This is my "hibernate.cfg.xml" file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">username</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I've found another similar problem here: [Hibernate - Cannot connect to DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15600101/hibernate-cannot-connect-to-db) but I still not understand what's wrong.

Best regards.
Andrea

Comment: Is the `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` class in your classpath?

Comment: Do you have hibernate config.prop file also in classpath?

Comment: Hi Robin and Nambari: I had to put my mysql driver's "Path" library also config.prop path to CLASSPATH variable, but i didn't do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Hibernate Mapping Wizard but as far as I know this is useful to create a hibernate mapping file with an extension `.hbm.xml`: see [this link](http://wiki.netbeans.org/HibernateMappingWizard) as reference.

So the result is a .hbm.xml file that is the mapping of your class to your table.

The point is the in your `hibernate.cfg.xml` there is no explicit reference to this .hbm.xml file.

Try to add:

`<mapping resource="<your_generated_file>.hbm.xml"/>`

in your `hibernate.cfg.xml` and be sure to give all the data needed when using the Hibernate Mapping Wizard tool.

Hope this will be useful!

Ciao!

Answer (score 0):

Nambari and Paolo,

I had to put my config.prop's and mysql driver's "Path" library into CLASSPATH variable. Now it works.

Thankyou all!

Ciao Paolo, grazie!